# RESTSerializer extend not affecting Ember data objects

Tags: ember.js, sails.js

JSON from Sails responses don't have root elements.  Ember data requires that the JSON be wrapped in a root element with the same name as the object.  The plan is to extend RESTSerializer to munge the JSON on the client side, because I don't have similar control over the server that I'm getting this data from.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn't seem like my Accounts model is using my AccountSerializer...

This is my Serializer:

```
var AccountSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
/**
 The current ID index of generated IDs
 @property
 @private
 */
_generatedIds: 0,
/**
 Sideload a JSON object to the payload

 @method sideloadItem
 @param {Object} payload   JSON object representing the payload
 @param {subclass of DS.Model} type   The DS.Model class of the item to be sideloaded
 @param {Object} item JSON object   representing the record to sideload to the payload
 */
sideloadItem: function(payload, type, item){
    var sideloadKey = type.typeKey.pluralize(), // The key for the sideload array
        sideloadArr = payload[sideloadKey] || [],   // The sideload array for this item
        primaryKey = Ember.get(this, 'primaryKey'), // the key to this record's ID
        id = item[primaryKey];

    // Missing an ID, generate one
    if (typeof id == 'undefined') {
        id = 'generated-'+ (++this._generatedIds);
        item[primaryKey] = id;
    }

    // Don't add if already side loaded
    if (sideloadArr.findBy("id", id) != undefined){
        return payload;
    }

    // Add to sideloaded array
    sideloadArr.push(item);

    payload[sideloadKey] = sideloadArr;
    return payload;
},

/**
 Extract relationships from the payload and sideload them. This function recursively
 walks down the JSON tree

 @method sideloadItem
 @param {Object} payload   JSON object representing the payload
 @paraam {Object} recordJSON   JSON object representing the current record in the payload to look for relationships
 @param {Object} recordType   The DS.Model class of the record object
 */
extractRelationships: function(payload, recordJSON, recordType){

    // Loop through each relationship in this record type
    recordType.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship) {
        var related = recordJSON[key], // The record at this relationship
            type = relationship.type;  // belongsTo or hasMany

        if (typeof related === "object" && related !== null){

            // One-to-one
            if (relationship.kind == "belongsTo") {
                // TODO: figure out when we need to only sideload 1 item we don't need to pluralize
                // Sideload the object to the payload
                this.sideloadItem(payload, type, related);

                // Replace object with ID
                recordJSON[key] = related.id;

                // Find relationships in this record
                this.extractRelationships(payload, related, type);
            }

            // Many
            else if (relationship.kind == "hasMany") {

                // Loop through each object
                related.forEach(function(item, index){

                    // Sideload the object to the payload
                    this.sideloadItem(payload, type, item);

                    // Replace object with ID
                    related[index] = item.id;

                    // Find relationships in this record
                    this.extractRelationships(payload, item, type);
                }, this);
            }

        }
    }, this);

    return payload;
},


/**
 Overrided method
 */
extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var typeKey = type.typeKey,
        typeKeyPlural = typeKey.pluralize(),
        newPayload = {};

    newPayload[typeKeyPlural] = payload;

    payload = newPayload;

    console.log(payload);


    // Many items (findMany, findAll)
    if (typeof payload[typeKeyPlural] != "undefined"){
        payload[typeKeyPlural].forEach(function(item, index){
            this.extractRelationships(payload, item, type);
        }, this);
    }

    for(var key in payload) {
        if(key === typeKeyPlural) {
            for(var i =0; i < payload[key].length; i++) {
                if(typeof payload[key][i] !== 'object') {
                    delete payload[key][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
},

extractSingle: function (store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    console.log('what is happening');
    var typeKey = type.typeKey,
        typeKeyPlural = typeKey.pluralize(),
        newPayload = {};

    if(typeof payload[typeKey] !== "object") {
        newPayload[typeKey] = payload;
        payload = newPayload;

        if(payload[typeKey] instanceof Array) {
            payload[typeKey] = payload[typeKey][0];
        }
    }


    if (typeof payload[typeKey] === "object"){
        this.extractRelationships(payload, payload[typeKey], type);

        delete payload[typeKeyPlural];
    }

    console.log(payload);


    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
}
});
export default AccountSerializer;
```

In my adapters/account.js I have the following:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var AccountAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: 'http://localhost:5000',
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return type + '.json';
  },
  serializer: AccountSerializer
});

export default AccountAdapter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure where you got the `serializer` property from, but I'm not sure that actually exists. There's a [defaultSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_defaultSerializer) property on the adapter which would work, but that comes with a bit of weird precedence rules. If I were you, I would declare the serializer in the Ember CLI way by putting it in `serializers/account.js` and remove the `serializer` property from your adapter.